# Cannot convert type to constrained generic of exact same type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm curious as to why this is a compilation error:

```
public abstract class AbstractThingList<T> : List<T>
{
    protected QueryBuilder<TH> Query<TH>(string query) where TH : AbstractThingList<T>
    {
        // Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AbstractThingList<T>' to 'TH'
        return new QueryBuilder<TH>(this, query);
    }

    protected class QueryBuilder<TH> where TH : AbstractThingList<T>
    {
        private readonly TH Container;

        public QueryBuilder(TH container, string query)
        {
            Container = container;
        }

        public TH Execute()
        {
            return Container;
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the error message `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AbstractThingList<T>' to 'TH'`,  however QueryBuilder constrains `TH` to `AbstractThingList<T>` (the exact same `T` as used in the outer class), of which "this" is most definitely an instance of.

Have I missed something?

Comment: `TH` is an `AbstractThingList<T>` but `this` is only guaranteed to be an `AbstractThingList<T>` and not necessarily a `TH`.

Comment: Ahh, got it.  If you want to post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `Query` method, while `TH` is constrained to be a subtype of `AbstractThingList<T>`, the type of `this` is `AbstractThingList<T>` and it is not necessarily a subtype of `TH`. A simple counterexample would be:

```
public class ThingList1 : AbstractThingList<string> { }

public class ThingList2 : AbstractThingList<string> {
   private void SomeMethod() {
       this.Query<ThingList1>("query")
   }
}
```

this is correctly disallowed since `ThingList2` is not a subtype of `ThingList1`.